# Trying to set an <a> tag on table data wrapped in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm retrieving some data from my database and using PHP to display it. That part it working fine. I then want the data presented to be a link as well. I've been trying to wrap my output inside an `<a>` tag, but so far without succes.

I can't figure out why there is no link to be found on my data when I wrapped it inside an `<a>` tag:

```
<?php

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
     echo
     "<tr>
      "?> <a href="http://example.com"> <?php echo "<td>


      {$row['Exam']} //This is my output

     </td>"?></a>
     </tr>\n";
        }   ?>
```

Comment: if you properly code, you will not face this  issue, its just your missing tags, only use echo when you have php variable, or use completly, for html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code cannot decide if it is HTML or PHP. Why not use PHP for all:

```
echo '<tr><td><a href="http://example.com">'.$row['Exam'].'</a></td></tr>'.PHP_EOL;
```

I also put the `<a>` inside the `<td>` table cell tag, and you might have a quoting problem.

Alternatively, if you start with HTML you could do this:

```
<tr><td>
  <a href="http://example.com"><?php echo $row['Exam']; ?></a>
</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified version with **correct** tags' sequence (you cannot wrap `td` in `a`).

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://example.com">
            <?=$row['Exam']?>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The link should be inside the <td>

> <td><a href="http://example.com">Link Name </a></td>